# Visual Studio can't handle my unity scripts

Tags: unity, c#, scripting, visual-studio, .net

I have created a new project in Unity 2018.3.4f1 with Visual Studio Community 2017.
I can't edit scripts properly in Visual Studio because of a bunch of errors related to .net framework. How can I fix these issues?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems you don't have the Unity plug-in for VS Community. The project should open as a C# assembly project like the following.

[image]

It's in tools and features, go get it.

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: I have checked this module. It is already there. I also updated visual studio. No effect.